# Jekyll use config.yml values in the HTML

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to setup configuration values within the config.yml file and have them be printed within the HTML page within Jekyll? I would like to set the default title and description of my website within the config.yml file and have them printed out in the header of all my layouts.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Every template has a `site` variable, which contains the settings from `_config.yml`. For example, if you have something like `my_setting: "string"` in `_config.yml`, you can access the value in a template using `{{ site.my_setting }}`.

**Note:** if you are using `jekyll serve`, you will need to restart the process for changes to take place. Indeed, `_config.yml` is not reloaded with the watch option.

Comment: It's `_config.yml`. +1, though.

Comment: Could somebody explain why this doesn't work for me? I can access the site variable but my custom configurations are not present within the hash.

Comment: Ok, since I can't edit my answer, I'll answer my own question: Jekyll will use a default configuration if it doesn't find an _config.yml OR you don't supply your own. In my case, the path to the _config.yml file was incorrect.

Comment: And here's another - make sure you reload your jekyll serve if you change your _config.yml.  (`jekyll serve --watch` doesn't reload config.)

Comment: how to escape html when puting them in config.yml?

Comment: is it possible to check site variables in your config using an if blog?

`{{% if site.webfont == true %}}
   blah
  {{% endif %}}`

This doesn't seem to work for me. Blah is printed all the time, regardless of whether site.webfont is true or false.